# How do i call a same function from the beginning for every button i have in the scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to write a function which increases the value of a variable each time it is called when a button is pressed. And it should start the count from zero for every button i attach it to. Please help me guys.
Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried and what are your actual issues getting the problem solved. Also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is very very broad ... I have time so here you go

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class ClickCounter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int CounterValue = 0;

    private Button _button;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _button.onClick.AddListener(() => 
        {
            CounterValue ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help bro.

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to mark the answer as Accepted Answer if it solves your question